# Was Zoe Kravitz's casting as Catwoman in The Batman related to her casting as Catwoman in The LEGO Batman Movie?

Tags: dc, batman, the-lego-batman-movie, catwoman, the-batman

In the 2022 film *The Batman*, Zoe Kravitz portrays a compelling, grounded version of Selina Kyle/Catwoman unlike most of the versions seen on-screen. However, this is not her first time portraying the character. In fact, she voiced Catwoman five years earlier in *The LEGO Batman Movie*. I'm sure it was coincidental, but did her portrayal of one version of the character influence her being cast as another version? Has it ever been commented on by the filmmakers or Kravitz herself?

Comment: ...And if so, is there a version of The Batman where Riddler was played by Conan O'Brien?

Answer (score 3):

Zoe Kravitz [wanted to audition for Catwoman in 2012's *The Dark Knight Rises*](https://www.glamour.com/story/zoe-kravitz-was-told-she-was-too-urban-to-audition-for-the-dark-knight-rises)

> But Kravitz wanted to enter the Batverse 10 years ago, when Christopher Nolan was completing his Dark Knight trilogy with 2012's The Dark Knight Rises (in which Anne Hathaway played Selina Kyle). In a recent interview she revealed that she didn't get to audition for that movie because of her mixed-race heritage.

It's likely that attempted audition helped net her that role in both *LEGO Batman* (2017) and *The Batman*.

Comment: *"In a recent interview she revealed that she didn't get to audition for that movie because of her mixed-race heritage."* I am NOT happy that someone as talented as Kravitz was denied the chance to audition because of racism.

Comment: @Astrid_Redfern A bit of devil's advocacy here: 1. Catwoman (like many secondary characters) has been portrayed as both black and white (i.e. Eartha Kitt and Michelle Phiffer). 2. Kravitz was not as well known in 2010 (when casting for TDKR happened) and 3. [Hathaway had her own headwinds](https://movieweb.com/anne-hathaway-catwoman-the-dark-knight-rises-casting-backlash/). I can't say how much of a role race played here, but [I would caution you from jumping to conclusions](https://people.com/movies/zoe-kravitz-addresses-comments-about-urban-casting-avoidance-the-dark-knight-rises/)